# Windows Phone 8: How to set Image on the fly

Tags: windows-phone-8

**Windows Phone 8 :**

I have an HTML design to bind in webbrowser control.

In that HTML I need to set the image() dynamically from my windows 8 phone application itself (Eg:MyApp/Images/Done.png).

How to set this Image in my HTML dynamically?

Could any one help me on that?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of Zen, WP8 tried to align Uris as close as possible to [Win8 Uris](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781229.aspx). So whenever you ask yourself "How do WP8 Uris work?" a good starting point would be Win8 and WP7 behaved. For example, you'll see lots of "*ms-appx:///*" and "*ms-appdata:///*" all around WP8.

Specfically, In order to access an app's Image resources from a WebBrowser just specify the local file path.For example, start a new WP8 project and in MainPage.xaml add:

```
<phone:WebBrowser Source="myPage.html" />
```

And create myPage.html and add:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <img src="Assets/AlignmentGrid.png"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

This would render the correct image as part of the WebBrowser. See attached [image].